# Datatables not formatting correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i&amp;subset=latin-ext">
<script src="./assets/js/require.min.js"></script> 
<link href="./assets/plugins/charts-c3/plugin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="./assets/plugins/charts-c3/plugin.js"></script>
<script>
  requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: '.'
  });
</script>
<link href="./assets/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

My Datatables aren't formatting correctly, I believe it's because of the order of the tags in the head. Does anyone know why the datatables may not be working based on the head?

Comment: Try moving `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css">` to the very bottom

Comment: nope, still the same issue. The issue is that the whole div is scrolling horizontally and the search bar is not staying fixed and I have it working on another page which is working fine. Which is why I think it is an issue with the head

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to delete this line

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

there is a conflict between the `datatable cdn bootstrap` and fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css

Comment: keep the `jquery.dataTables.min.js`  but then remove the  `bootstrap` one

Comment: that's done it! Thank you, can you explain what the issue was? confliction?

Comment: can you share an image on what the table look like

Comment: do you know how to add child rows using json data?

Comment: i have updated the answer with explanation  if this helped please conceder accepting the answer as it will help someone in the future

Comment: you can add child rows when you pass data from the api when you initialise the table